# Mean Value Calculation

Tags: statistics

A group of 20 values has the mean of 85 and the median of 80. A different group of 30 values has the mean of 75 and the median of 72.

a) What is the mean of the 50 values?
b) What is the median of the 50 values?

Answer (score 0):

I will use this notation for the two groups:

---

X{${{x_1, x_2, ... ,x_{20}}} $} and 
Y{${{y_1, y_2, ... ,y_{30}}} $}

---

a)  We know that $\mu$(X) = 85 and $\mu$(Y) = 75.
To calculate the mean of the 50 values you need to add up all the elements of both groups and divide it by the total number of elements:

---

$\sum$($x_i$) = 85 * 20 = 1700 and $\sum$($y_i$) = 75 * 30 = 2250

---

$\mu$(X+Y) = $\cfrac{1}{50}$[ $\sum$($x_i$) + $\sum$($y_i$)] = 79.

---

b)  The median is the middle value in the list of numbers. If the list consists of even number of elements then it is the arithmetic mean of the two middle most elements.

In our case the median is the average of the 25th and 26th numbers from the combined group. As we don't have sufficient information regarding the two groups the median cannot be determined.
To explain this, lets suppose we have the groups as:

---

$X_1$ = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 80, 80, 169, 169, 169, 169, 169, 169, 169, 169, 179]

$X_2$ = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 78, 82, 169, 169, 169, 169, 169, 169, 169, 169, 179]

---

$Y_1$ = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 72, 72, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 155]

$Y_2$ = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 69, 75, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 155]

---

For $X_1$ and $Y_1$ the median is 76 .

For $X_2$ and $Y_2$ the median is 76.5 .

Hope this explained why we don't have enough information to compute the media for the two groups.